# Scala pattern matching if can be converted to some type

Tags: scala, playframework, pattern-matching

I am using Scala Play framework to get the request query parameter.

The only method I can use by Play is:

```
val param: Option[String] = request.getQueryString("isXxxx")
```

Then I want to do some pattern matching, so that only the param is Type of Boolean I want to continue otherwise return a BadRequest.

Only the param is an instance of type Boolean can be processed, otherwise stop? So how can I use Scala pattern matching to achieve this? Something like:

```
param match {
  case ??? => xxxService.xxx({here is Boolean})
  case _ => BadRequest
}
```

Not quite sure the syntax about match it both not None and is type of Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You can match an option as follows:

```
param match {
  case Some(x) => xxxService.xxx(x)
  case None => BadRequest
}
```

If you do not know the type, you can pattern match on type using `:`

```
param match {
  case x: Boolean => xxxService.xxx(x)
  case _ => BadRequest
}
```

Comment: For your second example, can I do type based on an option. Just put first and second example together.

Comment: @ttt You can, but it's only necessary if you really don't know the type of the variable. Scala will usually be able to infer the type and you need only match on the `Option`, not the type.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a custom extractor

```
object boolean {
  def unapply(s: String) = try {
    Some(s.toBoolean)
  } catch {
    case e: IllegalArgumentException => None
  }
}
```

and match like this:

```
param match {
  case Some(boolean(x)) => xxxService.xxx({here is Boolean})
  case _ => BadRequest
}
```

There is nothing like that in the Scala library though, you have to provide it yourself.